# Using pandoc to generate PDF from Markdown with inline style

Tags: html, pdf, pandoc

I'm looking to create a *mostly* markdown document, but would like to take advantage of inserting HTML when I might need a bit more control over formatting on a case-by-case basis. I have iaWriter on macOS and am able to do so, and from my understanding of markdown this is an included behaviour.

When using pandoc on my linux machine, however, some tags (most notably `<i>` tags at the moment) are not interpreted.

My markdown file is:

```
This _does_ work.
This does <i>not</i> work.

However, inserting a <p>tag</p> will create a line-break and new paragraph.
```

When I execute `pandoc -o test.pdf test.md` I get the result: [test.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCDhK.png)

I've tried a few extensions in the output (+raw_html, +inline_code_attributes) thinking maybe I was missing something but have so far not found an explanation.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I was unable to find it, and have so far been unable to source an answer.

Thank you.

---

Comment: To achieve this currently I *can* do

`pandoc -o test.html test.md && pandoc test.html -o test.pdf` but I was under the impression that markdown could do this without that step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [pandoc MANUAL: Creating a PDF](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf).

By default, pandoc will use LaTeX to create the PDF Therefore, raw HTML will be ignored and would only have an effect if your output format is HTML as well. However, you can use `wkhtmltopdf` instead of `pdflatex` to go from markdown to PDF via HTML, instead of via LaTeX.

From the [raw HTML extension docs](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_html):

> The raw HTML is passed through unchanged in HTML, S5, Slidy, Slideous, DZSlides, EPUB, Markdown, Emacs Org mode, and Textile output, **and suppressed in other formats**.

Comment: Thanks. That at least clarifies that it _was_ behaving as intended. I did read and try the `+raw_html` when converting but, although I received no error, the output, the code was (I'm inferring) still parsed through default LaTeX and so it was ignored.

No problem though, answer accepted.